# FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED error on Vercel and Nuxt deployment

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

Imported a Nuxt project from GitHub with `vercel.json` config:

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "nuxt.config.js",
        "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder"
      }
    ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "test-app-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue}": "eslint"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.24.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

and `nuxt.config.js`

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - test-app-v2',
    title: 'test-app-v2',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3,
        },
      },
    },
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
}
```

I have no API yet and this is the error log in function tab:

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same error when trying to deploy an SSR nuxt project using vercel.json and @nuxt/vercel-builder. The accepted answer obviously meant deploying it as a static site - have you found a solution to your original problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: updating the build command fixed OP's issue.

---

Do you even need the `vercel.json` here?
I've tried to host one of [my repo](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt-tailwind-typography-darkmode-boilerplate) there and it's working fine with those settings only.

[image]

Hosted there: https://nuxt-tailwind-typography-darkmode-boilerplate.vercel.app/

Vercel pretty much self-detected that it was a Nuxt project and almost aced it itself.

Comment: But this is not SSR, this is using generate, which is JS/client and not server rendered.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo not a Vercel specialist but indeed, I don't think that Vercel is exposing a Node.js server, it's for JAMstack only projects.

Comment: @kissu I'm not sure that's correct, Vercel explicitly states it supports SSR builds with Nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/vercel/#ssr-with-vercel

Comment: @fredrivett it's written serverless runtime. Not sure that you have a free Node.js running server. But if it fits into a serverless runtime, you can probably have SSR benefits, for sure.

Comment: @kissu yeah you're right that Vercel don't provide a free Node.js server to be fair, but it seems from my experience deploying a Nuxt app that the serverless functions offer comparable experience, allowing for Vue apps to render whilst JS is disabled

Comment: @fredrivett there are lighter solution to allow static Vue apps that are more suitable towards serverless hosting IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't the OPs aim to deploy it using SSR? Using build command `yarn generate` will just generate a static site.